# Publishing website using org-mode gives void function error

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am trying to create a website using org-mode from [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html). Having set everything up, when I go to the end of the line `(require 'org-publish)` and press <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>, I get the following error,

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function org-defvaralias)
>
> org-defvaralias(org-agenda-filter-preset org-agenda-tag-filter-preset)

It seems that the function `org-defvaralias` is void. How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you please provide your versions of Org-Mode and Emacs?

Comment: it is the latest version of org (7.9.3f) and emacs (24.3)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that's a function defined in [org-compat.el](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/plain/lisp/org-compat.el); try `M-: (require 'org-compat)`, which should load and execute that file if it's part of your Org-mode installation. (Emacs 24.3, Org 7.9.3f, does appear to include it, so if you're using a current Emacs, you should be good to go.)

Comment: It did not help, I tried putting it right in the beginning in the buffer and also evaluated it separately.